# CSS Select every 4th child not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The nth-child selector nth-child(4n) should normally select every fourth child matching.

I have an example which matches every 3rd child, and I don't know why.

Could you help me with this?

```
.line_4:nth-child(4n){
   background: #ff0000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YPRB9/33/

```css
.line_4:nth-child(4n) {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="mod_article first last block" id="article-591">
  <h1 class="ce_headline first"> Kategorieübersicht</h1>
  <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
    <h3>hydraulische Handpumpen</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
    <h3>elektr.Hydraulikpumpen</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
    <h3>Handhebelventile &amp; Steuerventile</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
    <h3>Hydraulikschläuche</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
    <h3>Hydraulikkupplungen</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
    <h3>Hydraulikverschraubungen</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
    <h3>Kardanringe und Lagerböcke</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="ce_text line_4 last block">
    <h3>Hydraulikventile</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the fiddle/code, what you are doing here is this:

- Apply red background to the element with class **line_4** (this is clear), **but only if the element is 4th child** which means the parent is `<div class="mod_article first last block" id="article-591">` and the 1st child is the .

So basically if you want to achieve what you want to achieve without touching the CSS you should move h1 outside the parent div, or if you want without touching the HTML then as @Rion Williams suggested use **4n + 1**
:)

Answer (score 6):

The `nth-child()` pseudo-class counts *all* children of the same parent.

It appears you're trying to count all elements containing the class `line_4`. The selector doesn't care about `class`.

It starts counting from the first child, which happens to be `h1` in your code.

Since all elements with class `line_4` also happen to be divs, and there are no other div siblings in the container, consider using `nth-of-type()` instead ([revised demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YPRB9/40/)).

More details in the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 2):

The `nth-child()` selector will include all children that have the same parent, additionally, it's going to include the first `<h1>` element along with your other classes, which throws things off by 1.

If you wanted to match every 4th element with your existing code, consider using `4n+1` as your nth-child argument (to start after the `<h1>` element)  :

```
.line_4:nth-child(4n + 1){
 background: #ff0000;
}
```

**Example**

```css
.line_4:nth-child(4n + 1){
 background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="mod_article first last block" id="article-591">
    <h1 class="ce_headline first"> Kategorieübersicht</h1>
    <div class="ce_text line_4 block">    
        <h3>hydraulische Handpumpen</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
        <h3>elektr.Hydraulikpumpen</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
        <h3>Handhebelventile &amp; Steuerventile</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
        <h3>Hydraulikschläuche</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
        <h3>Hydraulikkupplungen</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
        <h3>Hydraulikverschraubungen</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="ce_text line_4 block">
        <h3>Kardanringe und Lagerböcke</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="ce_text line_4 last block">
        <h3>Hydraulikventile</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:nth-of-type()` if you are using `line_4` class only on div elements so it should work in your example [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YPRB9/37/)

```
.line_4:nth-of-type(4n){
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [@Michael_B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39234932/1341949), the `:nth-child()` pseudo-selector applies to *all* children of the parent element. However, assuming that the tag structure of the `.mod_article` module will always be consistent with your example, you might try your luck with the `:nth-of-type` selector.

The critical difference between these two selectors: where `:nth-child()` considers *all* children, `:nth-of-type()` only looks at children elements of a given tag. So to get the desired result, I replaced your CSS (in your linked jsFiddle) to the following:

```
.mod_article > div:nth-of-type(4n){
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

In your markup the initial `<h1>` tag was throwing off the count by one, so we can use the `:nth-of-type()` selector to correct for this by targeting only divs. Sorry if my explanation is a bit convoluted– but try messing around with the `:nth-of-type()` selector in your jsFiddle; you should get the hang of it pretty quickly.

(More details on the `:nth-of-type()` selector at [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... Hope it will work

```
.line_4:nth-child(4n-7) {  /* or 4n+1 */
   background: #ff0000;
}
```

And please look after about class. If i was there my code will be as like

```
li:nth-child(4n-7) {  /* or 4n+1 */
    color: green;   
}
```

or

```
.line:nth-child(4n-7) {  /* or 4n+1 */
       background: #ff0000;
  }
```